# Retrieving data from RDS gives AttributeError: 'sqlalchemy.cimmutabledict.immutabledict' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, attributeerror

I would like to retrieve user data from RDS whenever the API endpoint `{{url}}/api/users/login` is called to authenticate users, however, I am currently having issues with retrieving data from RDS.

#### Error stacktrace

This is the full stacktrace of the error:
[image]

#### Current package versions

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
flask-marshmallow==0.14.0
Flask-Migrate==2.5.3
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
marshmallow==3.10.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.24.1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.0b1
python==3.7
```

#### My attempts to solve the problem

Some things that I've attempted to resolve the issue but to no avail are:

- using pymysql connector instead of mysqlconnector
- downgrade flask-marshmallow==0.11.0
- downgraded marshmallow==3.6.1
- downgraded marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.23.1

#### More info about my application set up

I have Dockerized my application and this is my current set up:

**app.py**

```
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
migrate = Migrate()

def register_extensions(app: Flask) -> None:
   db.init_app(app)
   migrate.init_app(app, db)
   ma.init_app(app)

def create_application() -> Flask:
   app: Flask = Flask(__name__)
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASSWORD}@{DB_INSTANCE}:{DB_PORT}"
   app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
   register_extensions(app)
   app.register_blueprint(users_urls.mod, url_prefix=f"/{BEP_PREFIX}/users")

   return app

 app = create_application()
 CORS(app)
```

**models.py**

```
class Accounts(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Accounts'
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    personnelID = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    userType = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False)
```

**service.py**

```
class UserService(Service):
    __model__ = Accounts

    def get(self, username):
        return Accounts.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

user_service = UserService()
```

**views.py**

```
from bep.users.services import user_service

class UserLogin(Resource):
   def post(self):
       data = request.get_json()

       try:
           userData = user_service.get("test")
       except Exception:
           error_str = traceback.format_exc()
           logger.error("This prints the stack", exc_info=True)
           return UserServiceError.to_response(error=error_str, comments="Something went wrong while logging in")
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using SQLAlchemy 1.4?  This looks like [this flask-sqlalchemy issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/885)

Comment: ah sorry my bad, I `pip freeze` in my virtual environment instead of docker bash. Thanks for pointing it out! I have updated the package versions accordingly. Do you have any idea as to how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is a [known issue](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/885) in flask-sqlalchemy, caused by changes in SQLAchemy 1.4.  Flask-sqlalchemy attempts to modify the SQLALchemy engine's URL, but these URLs are immutable in SQLAlchemy 1.4.

The problem is fixed in Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5+ ([changelog](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/changelog/#version-2-5-0)).

If upgrading Flask-SQLAlchemy is not possible, the issue can be worked around by specifying the SQLAlchemy version passed to `pip`, either via the command line

```
pip install --upgrade 'SQLAlchemy<1.4'
```

or in requirements.txt

```
SQLAlchemy<1.4
```

SQLAlchemy 1.4 went on general release on 15 March 2021.

Comment: Thank you. You saved our lives.

Comment: Thank you @snakecharmerb You saved my life too :)